# Assign address to void pointer passed by reference

Tags: c, void-pointers

First time caller, long time listener. I have a question about some void * pointer-ing and can't seem to find an explanation so maybe someone here can shed some light.

I have a handler function where (among other things) I declare a void pointer and pass it by reference down to some other function:

```
void some_handler(some args)
{
    void * p_out_data;
    some_other_function(&p_out_data);
    // ... do some stuff with p_out_data after some_other_function stores an address
}
```

In some_other_function I malloc some memory (how much depends on a few factors), copy a_bunch_of_data into it, and store its address in p_out_data so that some_handler can access a_bunch_of_data:

```
void some_other_function(void * pp_out_data)   // pp_out_data is the address of p_out_data
{    
    void * p = malloc(d_size); 
    memcpy(p, &a_bunch_of_data, d_size);
    memcpy(pp_out_data, &p, sizeof(p));
}
```

This all works well. My question is: Why is it that the only way that I can store the memory address returned by malloc() into p_out_data is by using memcpy? I tried to directly store the address in the dereferenced pointer:

```
*pp_out_data = malloc(d_size);
```

But I get an error about illegal use of void pointer. I know there are a bunch of rules about void pointers, so I am guessing there's a specific one that applies here?

Comment: pp_out_data should be a pointer to a `void*`. How do you write "pointer to a `void*`"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a *pointer to a pointer*, so define the function as such:

```
void some_other_function(void **pp_out_data)
{    
    void * p = malloc(d_size); 
    memcpy(p, &a_bunch_of_data, d_size);
    *pp_out_data = p;
}
```

Comment: I see what you did there, but two indirections is probably not ideal for the mere passing of a memory address.  See my comments above.

Comment: True, simply returning a `void *` would be preferable in this simple case. You could always post that as another answer, but I believe that mine is still instructive.

Comment: Yes! This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Also, returning a void * would work, but I guess I over simplified the problem for posting as I actually return a status code.

Answer (score 0):

`*pp_out_data` is not your pointer variable; it is *the data that your pointer variable points to.*

You've already dereferenced it, in other words.

If you're expecting the new address to be passed out of your function through your `pp_out_data` parameter, it doesn't work that way; the address in `pp_out_data` *is being passed by value.*

`return` the new address from the function instead:

```
void* some_other_function(void* pp_out_data)
{    
    void* p = malloc(d_size); 
    memcpy(p, &a_bunch_of_data, d_size);
    memcpy(pp_out_data, &p, sizeof(p));
    return p;
}
```